# Huffman Codes Logic Error Inside One of the Functions

Tags: c++, huffman-code

I wrote my version of Huffman Codes and it does not have any syntax errors. It compiles, but the output is not displaying the correct values. I have a logic error in some of my functions and I cannot find where I am making that mistake.

I have tried to debug it with MS Visual Studio debugger but it was not successful.

This is my version of the Huffman Codes.

*I am posting the whole program because I am not certain where is my error located.*

```
/*
    Author: Stevan Milic
    Date: 05.05.2018.
    Course: Data Structures II
    Professor: Dr. Claude Chaudet
    Description: Huffman Codes
*/
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib> 
using std::cout;
#define MAX_TREE_HEIGHT 1000

// A Huffman tree node 
struct MinHeapNode 
{
    char codeword; // I chose char because we are inputing alphabetic       letters

    // The reason why I chose unsigned data type is because an unsigned  integer can never be negative.
    // In this case the frequency and the capacity of a character cannot be negative.
    unsigned freq; // Frequency of the character - how many times does it occur

    struct MinHeapNode *left, *right; // Left and Right children
};

struct MinHeap // Collection of nodes
{
    unsigned size; // Size of the heap
    unsigned capacity; // Capacity of the heap
    struct MinHeapNode** array; // Heap node pointers array
};

// Function to dynamically alocate a new heap node with provided character   (codeword) and its frequency
struct MinHeapNode* newHeapNode(char codeword, unsigned freq)
{
    struct MinHeapNode* temp = (struct MinHeapNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct   MinHeapNode));

    temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    temp->codeword = codeword;
    temp->freq = freq;

    return temp;
}

// Creating a new dynamically allocated min heap with given capacity
struct MinHeap* createMinHeap(unsigned capacity)
{
    struct MinHeap* minHeap = (struct MinHeap*)malloc(sizeof(struct MinHeap));
    minHeap->size = 0; // Setting the size to 0
    minHeap->capacity = capacity; // Inserting the given capacity
    // Inserting into the heap node pointers array
    minHeap->array= (struct MinHeapNode**)malloc(minHeap->capacity * sizeof(struct MinHeapNode*)); 
    return minHeap;
}

// Swap function to swap two min heap nodes
void swap(struct MinHeapNode** a, struct MinHeapNode** b)
{
    struct MinHeapNode* temp2 = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp2;
}
// minHeapify function 
void minHeapify(struct MinHeap* minHeap, int index)
{
    int smallest = index;
    int leftSon = 2 * index + 1;
    int rightSon = 2 * index + 2;

    if (leftSon < minHeap->size && minHeap->array[leftSon]->freq <      minHeap->array[smallest]->freq)
        smallest = leftSon;

    if (rightSon < minHeap->size && minHeap->array[rightSon]-> freq < minHeap->array[smallest]->freq)
        smallest = rightSon;

    if (smallest != index)
    {
        swap(&minHeap->array[smallest], &minHeap->array[index]);
        minHeapify(minHeap, smallest);
    }
}

// Checking if the size of the heap is 1
int heapSizeOne(struct MinHeap* minHeap)
{
    return (minHeap->size == 1);
}

// Extracting minimum value node from the heap
struct MinHeapNode* extractMin(struct MinHeap* minHeap)
{
    struct MinHeapNode* temp = minHeap->array[0];
    minHeap->array[0] = minHeap->array[minHeap->size - 1]; 
    --minHeap->size;
    minHeapify(minHeap, 0);
    return temp;
}

// Inserting a new node into min heap
void insert(struct MinHeap* minHeap, struct MinHeapNode* minHeapNode)
{
    ++minHeap->size;
    int i = minHeap->size - 1;
    while (i && minHeapNode->freq < minHeap->array[(i - 1) / 2]->freq) 
    {
        minHeap->array[i] = minHeap->array[(i - 1) / 2];
        i = (i - 1) / 2;
    }
    minHeap->array[i] = minHeapNode;
}

// Build function to build min heap
void build(struct MinHeap* minHeap)
{
    int n = minHeap->size - 1;
    for (int i = (n - 1) / 2; i >= 0; --i)
        minHeapify(minHeap, i);
}

// Display function to print an array
void display(int arr[], int n)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::cout << arr[i];
    std::cout << "\n";
}

// Function to check if the node is a leaf
int isLeaf(struct MinHeapNode* root)
{
    return !(root->left) && !(root->right);
}


// Creating a min heap with given capacity equivalent to size and inserts all    the codewords and their frequency.
struct MinHeap* create(char codeword[], int freq[], int size)
{
    struct MinHeap* minHeap = createMinHeap(size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        minHeap->array[i] = newHeapNode(codeword[i], freq[i]);
    minHeap->size = size;
    build(minHeap);
    return minHeap;
}

// Function that builds the Huffman tree 
struct MinHeapNode* buildHT(char codeword[], int freq[], int size)
{
    struct MinHeapNode *left, *right, *top;

    // Creating a min heap with given capacity equivalent to size and inserts all the codewords and their frequency.
    struct MinHeap* minHeap = create(codeword, freq, size);

    // while loop runs as long as the size of heap doesn't reach 1 
    while (!heapSizeOne(minHeap)) 
    {
        // Getting the two minimums from min heap
        left = extractMin(minHeap);
        right = extractMin(minHeap);

        // The frequency of top is computed as the sum of the frequencies of left and right nodes. 
        top = newHeapNode('_', left->freq + right->freq);
        top->left = left;
        top->right = right;
        insert(minHeap, top);
    }
    // The remaining value is the root node which completes the tree
    return extractMin(minHeap);
}

// Prints huffman codes from the root of
// Displaying Huffman codes
void displayHC(struct MinHeapNode* root, int arr[], int top)
{

    // Left side is given the value 0 
    if (root->left) 
    {
        arr[top] = 0;
        displayHC(root->left, arr, top + 1);
    }
    // Right side is given the value 1
    if (root->right) 
    {
        arr[top] = 1;
        displayHC(root->right, arr, top + 1);
    }
    // If this is a leaf node, print the character and its code.
    if (isLeaf(root)) 
    {
        std::cout << root->codeword << ": ";
        display(arr, top);
    }
}

// Building a Huffman Tree and displaying the codes
void HuffmanCodes(char codeword[], int freq[], int size)

{
    // Building a HT
    struct MinHeapNode* root = buildHT(codeword, freq, size);

    // Displaying the HT we built
    int arr[MAX_TREE_HEIGHT], top = 0;

    displayHC(root, arr, top);
}

// I used the example from the PP presentation in the Files section - The Hoffman Coding
int main()
{
    std::cout << "A|4\t B|0\t C|2\t D|1\t C|5\t E|1\t F|0\t G|1\t H|1\t I|0\t J|0\t K|3\t L|2\t M|0\t N|1\t\nO|2\t P|0\t Q|3\t R|5\t S|4\t T|2\t U|0\t V|0\t W|1\t X|0\t Y|0\t Z|0\t _|6\n" << endl;
    char arr[] = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', '_' };
    int freq[] = { 4, 0, 2, 1, 5, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 3, 5, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 6};

    int size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    HuffmanCodes(arr, freq, size);

    std::cout << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

For example, I expect the code to output A: 0101 but it outputs A: 001
Another example, I expect C to be C: 1111 but it outputs C: 11111

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon.  Do not dual tag questions with both the C and C++ tags unless the question is about how C and C++ interact.  Use one of the two language tags.  The code in your question uses `#include <iostream>` and `using std::cout;` which means it is clearly C++; using the C tag is wholly inappropriate for such a question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Some people say that this is mostly C-ish program because I do not use any of the modern C++ features, that is why I used both tags.

Comment: You're using the C++ I/O library — it cannot be compiled by a C compiler; therefore, it is not C code.  That you're using `malloc()` instead of `new` is a separate problem.  If you're learning C, don't use C++ features.  If you're learning C++, don't use C features such as `malloc()` et al.  I designated it as C++ by looking at the first three non-comment lines — they are none of them lines that would be expected in a C program, and the third absolutely cannot appear in a C program. (AFAICT, even if you do preprocessor hacking, the double colon cannot be made to pass a pure C compiler.)

Comment: You've got expectations and you've got a good debugger. That's the right place to start. What you want to do with the debugger is watch closely and see where your expectations are violated. This is either the bug, where the bug becomes visible and you'll have to work your expectations backwards to find where the bug is. Or your expectations are wrong. I would draw the tree with pen on paper. I would then print out the tree the program generates and compare. Armed with the differences between the two, I would then step through the building of the tree to see where it went awry.

Comment: If there are no differences between the paper tree and the computer tree, I would (at this point) assume my expectations are correct and look at how I transform the tree into the Huffman code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you have any problem in your code. In fact the problem is in your question, since you are assuming that there is a single correct Huffman code for a given distribution. This is never true. You have many possible Huffman codes even when lengths are not interchangeable, just by changing 0 and 1 at any node. In your specific case you have C which belongs to the group CMPU of letters with frequency 2. You can exchange their lengths and codes as you wish without impacting the average code length. In particular two should have a length of 5 and two should have a length of 4. Check if this is true in your manually built output. The same holds for A, which has a frequency of 4 as T. So you should check if A and T have a code length of 3 and 4 or viceversa.

An easy check is to compute the average code length of your distribution, which should be   3.886, pretty near to the Entropy which is 3.818.

I don't think you checked the order in which the data is returned after being placed in the heap, so weird things may happen.